# Django-mptt get cumulative count of item inside each category

Tags: django, django-mptt

I'm using django-mptt.

I'm trying to get all categories with the count of items inside each category.

But I get this error:

```
OperationalError at /items/
(1054, "Unknown column 'items_category.lft' in 'where clause'")
```

From my view.py

```
    categories = Category.objects.add_related_count(
        Category.objects.all(),  # Queryset
        Item,  # Related mobile
        'category',  # Name of the foreignkey field
        'count',  # Name of the property added to the collection
        cumulative=True)  # Cumulative or not.
        
    print(categories)
```

model.py

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, )
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by=['name']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('slug', 'parent',)    
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"   

class Item(models.Model):
    category = TreeForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250 )
```

Using `print(categories.query)` query generated is:

```
SELECT `items_category`.`id`, `items_category`.`name`, `items_category`.`slug`, `items_category`.`parent_id`, `items_category`.`lft`, `items_category`.`rght`, `items_category`.`tree_id`, `items_category`.`level`, (SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT U0.`id` FROM `items_item` U0 INNER JOIN `items_category` U1 ON (U0.`category_id` = U1.`id`) WHERE (U1.`lft` >= `items_category`.`lft` AND U1.`lft` <= `items_category`.`rght` AND U1.`tree_id` = `items_category`.`tree_id`)) _count) AS `count` FROM `items_category` ORDER BY `items_category`.`tree_id` ASC, `items_category`.`lft` ASC
```

I tried to fix query generator trying it directly on my database and seems query is correct but syntax is very wrong.

The correct and working query is that I just removed `.

```
SELECT items_category.id, items_category.name, items_category.slug, items_category.parent_id, items_category.lft, items_category.rght, items_category.tree_id, items_category.level, 
    (
        SELECT count(*) 
            FROM (
                SELECT U0.id 
                FROM items_item U0 
                INNER JOIN items_category U1 ON ( U0.category_id = U1.id) 
                WHERE (U1.lft >= items_category.lft 
                       AND U1.lft <= items_category.rght 
                       AND U1.tree_id = items_category.tree_id
                )
            ) _count
    ) AS count 
                       FROM items_category 
ORDER BY items_category.tree_id 
    ASC, items_category.lft ASC
```

Comment: Perhaps you haven't run the migration? `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: yes i did migrations and still dosen't work

Comment: Here's some troubleshooting I can think of: make sure you've run `makemigrations` and `migrate`, try to pass the app name if the error persists, try to use a new empty DB. If the error is still there, you could create an example project on GitHub to demonstrate the problem and make it easier for others to examine.

Comment: atm i can't add/share my project ... however i added some info to my question....
the query generated is correct but have some ' give problems to query

Comment: Hmm, interesting. So the problem lies on the backtick \`.  I'm curious, do other queries (ex. `User.objects.all()`) also use backtick? And another thing to check, does the query succeed if you only include `Category`'s direct field (append the query with `.values('name', 'slug', 'parent')`).

Comment: all i found something very strange... 
i'm testing with 2 different databases on 2 different PC on local...
add_related_count works on Postgress... same code on phpMyadmin dosen't work.... all other pages of django app and pages works well even where i use category exept where i call add_related_count

only on MySql, testing the query get error 'lft' colum dosen't exist but when i check Database it's exist

Comment: So, the main problem lies between MySQL and `add_related_count`.  Have you tried different versions of MySQL? And just to make sure. have you tried SQLite? It's relatively simple than the other database backends since it doesn't require DBMS installation.

Comment: i've tried to upgrade mysql on XAMPP but the problem still continue ... seem cannot find colums of where clause....
instead with Sqlite and postgress works all perfectly